# Require login based on parameter?

Tags: php, security, symfony

Is it possible to require a sandbox login with a parameter `sandbox: true` and not when `sandbox: false`?  The closest I can get is creating a voter that does this:

#### voter snippet:

```
    if (!$user instanceof UserInterface && $this->sandbox) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
    }
    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
```

But this is not sufficient because it needs

```
* @Security("has_role('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')")
```

at the top of a controller to be triggered. And then even when `sandbag: false`, login is required!

#### security.yml

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        access_denied_url: /login
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            failure_path:    /message/inactive
            failure_forward: true
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    ~    
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

So does the sandbox switch need to get inside security.yml?  If so, how?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any sandbox parameter in [Security reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html). Is this directly related to Symfony or some project built on top of it?

Comment: @s7anley: `sandbox: ` is added in parameters.yml.  It's intended to be a key to turn sandbox on or off.  I just haven't gotten there yet.  So `sandbox` is not a Symfony default parameter.